# Jenkinsfile: how to deploy and run artifacts on another node

Tags: windows, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a test project to help me validate a **PoC** for a jenkins pipeline.
It's fairly simple and consists of 2 distinct nodes (*master* and *sim*).

It's a VS C++ project, thus on **master node** I need to perform:

- code checkout
- build
- archive the artifacts (to be reused later)
- run some static code analysis

And on the **sim node**, I need to perform:

- deploy the build artifacts (from the archive stage)
- run some testing

I've almost got it to work, just being stuck on the sim node, where for some reason Jenkins is performing a code checkout there!? Where I only need it to fetch the binaries and run some tests. Don't how to get around this.

Sim nodes don't have access to the SCM repo as they don't need to deal with source code.

Here's the declarative pipeline script I've used so far:

```
pipeline {

agent {
    node {
        label 'master'
    }
}

environment {
    Path = 'C:\\"Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio"\\2017\\Professional\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\amd64;C:\\Windows\\System32;C:\\local\\boost_1_67_0\\lib64-msvc-14.1;%Path%'
}

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            bat 'msbuild "testproj\\testproj.sln" /t:rebuild /p:platform=x64 /p:configuration=Release'
        }
    }
    stage('Archive') {
        steps {
            archiveArtifacts '**/*.lib, **/*.exe, **/*.xml'
        }
    }
    stage('SCA') {
        steps {
            bat '"C:\\Program Files\\Cppcheck\\cppcheck" --language=c++ --enable=all --xml --xml-version=2 . 2> cppcheck-result.xml'
            publishCppcheck pattern: 'cppcheck-result.xml'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        node('Sim') {
            steps {
                copyArtifacts filter: '**/*.exe', fingerprintArtifacts: true, flatten: true, projectName: 'test', selector: lastSuccessful()
                bat 'ut.exe --log_format=XML --log_level=all --log_sink=ut_results.xml'
                xunit testTimeMargin: '3000', thresholdMode: 1, thresholds: [], tools: [BoostTest(deleteOutputFiles: true, failIfNotNew: true, pattern: '**/ut_results.xml', skipNoTestFiles: false, stopProcessingIfError: true)]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Jenkins' job console log:

```
...
[Pipeline] publishCppcheck
[Cppcheck] Starting the cppcheck analysis.
[Cppcheck] Processing 1 files with the pattern 'cppcheck-result.xml'.
[Cppcheck] Not changing build status, since no threshold has been exceeded.
[Cppcheck] Ending the cppcheck analysis.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] node
Running on Sim in c:\jenkins\workspace\test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url [git repo] # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
...
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git.exe fetch --no-tags --progress [git repo] +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
options {
    skipDefaultCheckout()
}
```

Then a checkout stage:

```
stage('Clone repo') {
    steps {
        checkout scm
    }
}
```